# sharepoint site report card

Tags: site, reports

Our SP report card health status says that our site has only been viewed 8 times in the last 30 days and this does not seem right.  We were wondering where this number comes from and if it properly reflects our site use.

Please suggest me how to proceed further

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you are reffering to the Web Analytics Web part (http://www.sharepointedutech.com/2010/03/12/out-of-the-box-web-analytics-web-part/). Reports are generated via the Web Analytics timer job. 
To troubleshoot you would need to make sure that:

1. "Usage and Data Health Data Collection" service is configured correctly.
2. "Log Collection Schedule" is configured correctly
3. "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Import" and "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Processing" Timer jobs are configured to run at regular intervals.

In addition, the Web Analytics Trigger Workflows Timer Job must be enabled and scheduled to run at regular intervals (for each site that you need analytics).